# How do I set expiration headers for CSS, JS, and Images for blogspot site

Tags: caching, blogger, pagespeed

I checked my [site](http://www.techzost.com) with google page speed.

It said Specify an expiration for my resources.

Can anyone tell me how to leverage browser caching for blogger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot set custom expiration for resources served by Blogger - that part is already done for you by Google servers. Having said that, if you serve content from any third party domains (which [you are](http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=42394)), then you should look into enabling compression and caching on those hosts.

Of course, sometimes this will be out of your control - ex, third party widgets which you do not control directly.

Comment: I host my CSS on Google Drive, so in my <head> I have <link> drive..../> - How would I set expiration on that? Also Blogger.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set the expires header in your hosting settings. If you have hosted your website on `Google App Engine` (which is free) you can set the expires header in `webapp-web.xml` to 10 days.

```
<include path="/assets/**.css" expiration="10d" /> 
<include path="/assets/**.js" expiration="10d" />
```

I have gone through your site and have seen that you use blogger for articles, you can not set the expires header for blogger images and posts.

I have used `Google`'s infrastructure to host my images, `CSS` and `JS` files. But if you want to improvise your pagespeed score on you custom JS files and CSS files, [my blogger post](http://blog.recurtrix.com/2012/08/free-hosting-for-your-web-applications.html) can help you to host static content in Google. My blogs pagespeed score is around 94.

**Disclaimer:** I have authored the post mentioned in the link.

If you are hosting your CSS and JS files in some other hosting location, you should look for help to set the `expires header` in case you are using `Apache` web server to host.